# uniformly Cauchy-sequence is uniformly convergent, proof verification

Tags: analysis, solution-verification

Let $D$ be any set and $(f_n:D \to \mathbb{R})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exist $N(\epsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$ with $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in D$ and $n,m> N$. Since $f_n(x)$ is a Cauchy-sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ we can define $f(x):=\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)$ for all $x \in D$.

I now want to proof that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$: Let $\epsilon>0$ and $N(\epsilon)$ as above. By continuity of $|\cdot|$ we get $|f_m(x)-f(x)|=|f_m(x)-\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x)|= \lim_{n \to \infty}|f_m(x)-f_n(x)|< \epsilon$ for all $x \in D$ and $m > N(\epsilon)$.

(I used $x_n<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$ implies $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n<\epsilon$)

Comment: This looks fine.

Comment: Could you show it without using $\lim$ in the $|f_m(x)-f(x)| < \epsilon$ calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two quibbles: At the start, say "$(f_n(x))$ is Cauchy for each $x$" ("$f_n(x)$" is a number). In the second paragraph, I think your first $f_n$ should be $f_m$.

Other than that, it is correct and succinct.

Comment: what do you mean with $(f(x_n))$?. For every Point $x \in D$ we get the sequence $f_n(x)$. And yes you are right with $f_m$.

Comment: Sorry, corrected now.

Comment: Just notation. A sequence would be written as $( f_n(x))$ or $\{f_n(x)\}$

Comment: Ok thanks for your comments